# How to read this Stack Text?

Tags: exception

I have a game crashing and I'm trying to narrow down the culprit.
I've done a little research and I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around this.
Using WinDbg and !analyze I've come up with this Stack Text:

```
STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`00f7df88 00000001`4185436e     : 00000000`e0df47c0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000020 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!ffxGetDeviceDX12+0x9bcb0
00000000`00f7df90 00000001`4b6c875d     : 00000000`00f7e300 00000000`9b425560 00000000`00000001 00000000`0777e9b0 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!Scaleform::Render::Matrix4x4<float>::SetIdentity+0x53c22e
00000000`00f7dfc0 00000001`4195e11d     : 00000000`9b425560 00000000`00000000 00000000`00f7e370 00000000`00000000 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!Scaleform::System::HasMemoryLeaks+0x3d3d5e5
00000000`00f7dff0 00000001`4193f33f     : 00000000`9b425560 00000000`9b425560 00000000`00f7e370 00000000`a44164e0 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!Scaleform::Render::Matrix4x4<float>::SetIdentity+0x645fdd
00000000`00f7e040 00000001`4193eaef     : 00000000`9b425560 00000001`407ffaf5 00000000`00000000 00000001`451aa1a0 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!Scaleform::Render::Matrix4x4<float>::SetIdentity+0x6271ff
00000000`00f7e070 00000001`41864b31     : 00000000`e0df47c0 00000000`9b425560 00000000`9b425560 00000000`00000000 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!Scaleform::Render::Matrix4x4<float>::SetIdentity+0x6269af
00000000`00f7e0f0 00000001`433ff3d5     : 00000000`9cf8a040 00000000`9cf8a088 00000000`b41f0010 00000000`00000000 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!Scaleform::Render::Matrix4x4<float>::SetIdentity+0x54c9f1
00000000`00f7e130 00000001`433e4a20     : 00001941`00036c6b 00000000`b41f0010 00000000`b41f0010 00000000`09afbef8 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!src_strerror+0x35f9d5
00000000`00f7e240 00000001`437b8d9e     : 00000000`00000003 00000000`00000003 00000000`00f7e370 00000000`00000001 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!src_strerror+0x345020
00000000`00f7e270 00000001`43b66162     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00f7e960 00000000`dbd02380 00000000`00f7e960 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!src_strerror+0x71939e
00000000`00f7e440 00000001`43b48239     : 00000000`28649200 00000000`09dba060 00000001`462db8b0 00000001`462db8b0 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!src_strerror+0xac6762
00000000`00f7e790 00000001`413bd1ce     : 00000001`451aa1a0 00000000`0a128510 00000000`00f7ec08 00000000`00000000 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!src_strerror+0xaa8839
00000000`00f7eb40 00000001`413f5aef     : 00000000`0c7e4600 00000000`09dba060 00000000`0ce70320 00000000`0c87f520 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!Scaleform::Render::Matrix4x4<float>::SetIdentity+0xa508e
00000000`00f7ed50 00000001`41aad14c     : 00000000`0d602b40 00000000`ffffffff 00000000`00000000 00000000`010e7370 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!Scaleform::Render::Matrix4x4<float>::SetIdentity+0xdd9af
00000000`00f7f060 00000001`413f63de     : 00000000`09dad780 00000000`22e37300 00000000`0000008c 00000000`00000000 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!Scaleform::Render::Matrix4x4<float>::SetIdentity+0x79500c
00000000`00f7f0c0 00000001`4146cc4e     : 00000000`2864a600 00000000`09dad780 00000000`df0f0868 00000000`00000000 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!Scaleform::Render::Matrix4x4<float>::SetIdentity+0xde29e
00000000`00f7f140 00000001`41430185     : 00000001`477142f8 00000000`de4aab00 00000000`ffffffff 00000000`00000000 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!Scaleform::Render::Matrix4x4<float>::SetIdentity+0x154b0e
00000000`00f7f180 00000001`41dff4be     : 00000001`47714280 00000000`00f7f238 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!Scaleform::Render::Matrix4x4<float>::SetIdentity+0x118045
00000000`00f7f1c0 00000001`407ed3d5     : 00000001`06554d40 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!Scaleform::Render::Matrix4x4<float>::SetIdentity+0xae737e
00000000`00f7f250 00000001`407f4410     : 00000000`ffffffff 00000000`ffffffff 00000000`00000000 00000000`7b5109e0 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!AK::MemoryMgr::GetGlobalStats+0x1905
00000000`00f7f4c0 00000001`407f44ba     : 00000000`07363880 00000000`07363880 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!AK::WriteBytesCount::Reserve+0x6aa0
00000000`00f7f630 00000001`40801054     : 00000000`0008001f 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!AK::WriteBytesCount::Reserve+0x6b4a
00000000`00f7f670 00000001`44db1b82     : 00000000`0000000a 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!AK::WriteBytesCount::Reserve+0x136e4
00000000`00f7fef0 00007ffe`1cb726ad     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : DeadIsland_Win64_Shipping!agsCheckDriverVersion+0x11e22
00000000`00f7ff30 00007ffe`1e60a9f8     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x1d
00000000`00f7ff60 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x28
```

Um... tried deciphering it.

Comment: The offsets (like +0x9bcb0) are very important.  You want at most +0x100, give or take, to rate the symbol as reasonably accurate.  As you can tell, clearly this stack trace is junk.  Obtain the .pdb files to improve accuracy.

Comment: @HansPassant I have no clue what you're talking about. It might as well have been in Japanese. The extent of my knowledge is knowing how to open the dump file. I just want to know what the stack text is telling me. Like what is the likely culprit causing the crash.

Comment: "junk" = doesn't tell you anything useful.

Comment: @HansPassant You're saying the dump file is useless for tracking down the cause of a crash? What's the point in the dump file then?